# Get response from webpage after x seconds of page loading (file_get_contents)

Tags: php, youtube

Is there any way of getting a webpage response after x seconds of it loading?

For example i want to create an api that gets the number of comments of a youtube video, but as you might know when you open a youtube video link its like 2 seconds loading the comments, so if you know any other way of getting the youtube comments number it would help as well, but if you can answer to the first question please answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There's going to be different ways of doing this but we need to know what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers I ended up using youtube api which before I wasn't able to use it but I've figured out how to use it.

I had only tried the file_get_content function because I didn't had no idea on how to do it, i've solved the problem but if someone knows how to do that please tell me, you never know when you might need it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily use apis and count comments throw it:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments